# Calculate total automatically from quantity and price

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Making Basic Web Application using `knockout js`.

I have `3` textboxes:

**1. price, 
2. quantity, 
3. total.**

I want to calculate total automatically when user add data in quantity & in price.

**html code :**

```
price:<input type="text" data-bind="value : itemPrice"><br/>
qty:<input type="text" data-bind="value : itemQTY"><br/>
total:<input type="text" data-bind="value : itemTotal">
```

**knockout js code :**

```
ViewModel = function() {
       var self = this;        
       self.itemPrice = ko.observable();
       self.itemQTY = ko.observable();
       self.itemTotal = ko.observable();
};
```

Suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ko.computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) :

```
self.itemTotal = ko.computed(function(){
  if(isNaN(self.itemPrice()) == true && isNaN(self.itemQTY()) == true || isNaN(self.itemQTY()) == true || isNaN(self.itemPrice()) == true){
        return '0.00';
  }else{
        return  self.itemPrice()*self.itemQTY();
  }
});
```

above condition will check that if user has entered `text data`, if user has entered text data then it ll automatically set to `0.00` otherwise calculate `total` on base of `input` then show in total `textbox`.

& make total textbox `readonly` so user can't edit it.
Like :

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value : itemTotal" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ko.computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

```
self.itemTotal = ko.computed(function() {
   return self.itemPrice()*self.itemQTY();
});
```

Comment: thank you its working, user3145373 ツ have have good answer with validation & make readonly textbox of total.